# For loop count 1 to 10 and then 10 to 1 alternatively, concatenated with a letter

Tags: javascript, java, for-loop, if-statement, nested-loops

How can I write a code with nested for-loop, that gives the following result:

```
W,1,1
W,1,2
W,1,3
W,1,3
W,1,2
W,1,1
W,2,1
W,2,2
W,2,3
W,2,3
W,2,2
W,2,1
etc...
```

**Note: These numbers are not always odd and even numbers, they may be decimal, but they are so here for simplifying**

I tried this, but wrong results:

```
var lon,lat,str ='',i = 0;

    for(lat=1; lat<=2; lat++)
    {
    if((i%2)==0){

        for(lon=1; lon<=3; lon++)
           {

            str+="W,"+lat+","+lon+"\n";
            console.log(str)
           }
               }
    else{

         for(lon=3; lon>=1; lon--)
           {

            str+="W,"+lat+","+lon+"\n";
            console.log(str)
           }
              }
                i++;   
         }
```

I thought, I would take a variable *i* as intermediate, with each time loop it is either odd or even via increment, then with *If...Else* I would decide when it should be counted forward or backwards.

Any idea

Please, coding with Java or Javascript, thx

Comment: use two loop inside each other

Comment: I can solve this for you, just bear with me for 5 or so minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a single nested loop if you use an intermediate array to store the inner loop data, then after the inner loop, join it to the result as well as its "reversed" data.

```js
var precision = 5,
  tmp = [],
  res = "",

  latStart = 10.1,
  latInc = 0.1,
  latTarg = 10.8,

  lonStart = 1.1,
  lonInc = 0.2,
  lonTarg = 2.4;

for (var latI = latStart; latI <= latTarg; latI=+(latI+latInc).toFixed(precision)) {
  tmp.length = 0;
  for (var lonI = lonStart; lonI <= lonTarg; lonI=+(lonI+lonInc).toFixed(precision)) {
    tmp.push("W," + latI + "," + lonI + "\n");
  }
  res += tmp.join("") + tmp.reverse().join("");
}

console.log(res);
```

Comment: please note that your script doesnt write the last result of serie as first row when reversing.  https://jsfiddle.net/L8sosgoy/

Comment: @Khaled: Updated.

Comment: @ Skinny Pete, please could I ask you a little when you are here?

Answer (score 1):

Use nested `for-loop`.

After the first nested `for-loop` ends, start a second with a reverse direction.

```js
let generate = (length) => {
  let artifacts = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
    let j;
    for (j = 1; j <= length; j++) {
      artifacts.push(`W,${i},${j}`);
    }

    for (--j; j > 0; j--) {
      artifacts.push(`W,${i},${j}`);
    }
  }
  
  return artifacts;
}

let array = generate(6);
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important
}
```

Comment: thx Ele, but could you give me a general form, e.g. I begin length = 3 as in your example, but I set also another value to, let us say, width = 6?

Comment: @Khaled look at the updated answer.  I've created a function which returns an array of strings.  The function receives the length of iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a good way to solve a problem is to solve it in steps. For example, you can make a method to count up and one to count down. Doing so not only makes problems easier to solve, but can also help make code more readable and easier to understand:

```js
var lat = 1, long = 1, latMax = 2, c = "W";

function countLongUp(max) {
  for(; long < max; ++long) print();
  print();  
}

function countLongDown(min) {
  for(; long > min; --long) print();
  print();  
}

function print() {
  console.log(c + "," + lat + "," + long);
}

for(; lat <= latMax; ++lat) {
  countLongUp(3);
  countLongDown(1);
}
```

Comment: Guys, I try all your scripts, why they fail when I give decimal numbers?!!

Comment: I wrote in my question: plz note the increment and decrement are not integers, they may be floating e.g. lat is increased by 0.1 to reach latMax and lon is increased by 0.2 to reach lonMax

Comment: @Khaled Your example has increments of +1 and -1, so everyone's example is doing that as well, along with that you *specifically* asked for that. You also need to note precision loss when using floats, for example `0.1 + 0.2 =
0.30000000000000004`.